# how to use protocol buffer in asp.net vnext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to serialize what my api returns using protobuff net library. I have seen example such as the following 
http://www.strathweb.com/2013/02/asp-net-web-api-and-protocol-buffers/

but I don't know how to handle it on aspnet vnext. I can't seem to find the HttpConfiguration which is needed? I think...I am new to aspnet vnext any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Bascially you need to write formatters (input and output) for the proto-buf format...I see that the formatter you pointed depends on `protobuf-net` nuget package...not sure if this package would be supported in `CoreCLR` yet, but you try and see if things work fine with `Desktop CLR` though...

Comment: thank you  @KiranChalla  will post solution when I implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the protobuf-portable-net package. Seems to be consumable for coreclr targets. https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-portable-net/